# How to find the SID in mysql to connect to Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

How can i find find the SID (Unique db connection file) of a mysql database for a connection to an oracle.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question or be a bit more precise?

Comment: I need the sid of mysql database for oracle db_link, there should a db connection file for mysql like tnsnames.ora for oracle

Comment: Never heard of anything like that for MySQL

Comment: and is the service name same as a database name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of creating an Oracle dbdlink to a MySQL database: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_create_database_link.htm.